# GCC std::thread not found in namespace std

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11

I am using GCC 4.5.0 with the Eclipse IDE (if that matters) on Windows via MinGW.

I'm using the `-std=c++0x` flag.

I find that `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` still isn't defined, so `thread` for me still isn't a member of namespace `std`. -- or perhaps it is something else.

What does one do to get C++11 threading support with GCC?

P.S. It doesn't recognize the `-pthread` flag. I read in a question elsewhere on this site that this works.

Edit: Stupid me: `pthread` is a library, not an option. It's installed, gcc can find the header, but still no cigar.

Comment: You are including `<thread>`, right?

Comment: Yes, how else did I find that macro?

Edit: Checked again. I am definitely including it. It still complains that "thread" isn't a member of std.

Comment: See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931181/723845)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Works fine on Linux (`g++ -std=c++0x -lpthread` with no additional defines).

However, [this thread on Cygwin mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/GCC-4.4.0---Can't-activate-threading-support-td23292063.html) suggests that, at least as of 4.4, _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS was disabled by an autoconf test when building libstdc++ because pthread implementation of cygwin is missing pthread_mutex_timedlock. Perhaps MinGW has the same problem.

Also, [this thread on comp.lang.c++.moderated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/a99db4f349287db7/6f5174c1bf2a3c36?lnk=gst&q=Summary+of+C%2B%2B0x+Feature+Availability#6f5174c1bf2a3c36) says the same thing. Not supported by the library.

Answer (score 4):

The native Windows builds of gcc do not support the new C++0x/C++11 thread library.

The (commercial) [Just::Thread](http://www.stdthread..co.uk) library adds support to the TDM port of gcc 4.5.2 for Windows, as well as MSVC.

Answer (score 3):

> What does one do to get C++0x threading support with GCC?

Use Boost?  Seriously http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html claims threads aren't complete even in mainline head so it isn't going to be in any current release.

Comment: Yes, I know about boost and I don't mind using it. I also know that gcc support for C++0x is currently experimental. I was just curious as to why it didn't work with mine when it worked with apparently older versions (which I have tried, and still end up getting the same message).

Answer (score 3):

Use this builts of mingw: http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/list

Answer (score 3):

There is already a lightweight header-only library that implements std::thread and sync primitives in pure win32 API:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

IT should work with any version of MinGW that has proper C++11 support.