# gcc 4.5.1 configure options for C++0x thread support

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to compile gcc 4.5.1 for cygwin with support for C++0x threads. 
However, the resulting gcc does not recognize the -pthread option.

My configure command is:

```
./configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc
            --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-libgomp
            --enable-libssp --enable-threads=posix --with-__thread
```

The sample program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void hello()
{
 cout << "Hello Concurrent World!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
 cout << "starting" << endl;
 thread t(hello);
 t.join();
 cout << "ending" << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I am compiling a C++ program using

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -std=c++0x -pthread Trial.cpp
gcc: unrecognized option '-pthread'
Trial.cpp: In function `int main()':
Trial.cpp:21:5: error: `thread' was not declared in this scope
Trial.cpp:21:12: error: expected `;' before `t'
Trial.cpp:22:5: error: `t' was not declared in this scope
```

My question is how should I configure gcc?

Comment: Are you sure you are using and understanding GCC correctly? I dont know a lot about it, but several things looks wrong.

Comment: Yes, I should have used g++. But it does not work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the error message, the problem is not with your configuration, but with your g++ option. Use

```
g++ -lpthread
```

for pthreads (POSIX threads) and

```
g++ -lboost_thread
```

for boost threads. (-pthread is wrong.)

see the manual of g++

```
man gcc
```

Comment: This is an uninformed advice. `-pthread` sets preprocessor flags and links against appropriate libraries, whereas `-lpthread` just links. For cygwin the correct option is `-threads` which is used for both compiling and linking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile your code with `g++` with just `-pthread` and `-std=c++0x` flags alone or with `gcc` using the previous flags plus `-lstdc++`.

However, when I used your flags, it did not work (the error was quite different though), so maybe try it with the following flags next time (because it does not have to necessarily be caused (only) by you compiling GCC with wrong config).

```
gcc -lstdc++ -std=c++0x -pthread your.cpp
g++ -std=c++0x -pthread your.cpp
```

Comment: Both options give the same error that -pthread option is unrecognized.
I suspect the issue is with cygwin as outlined in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414834/gcc-stdthread-problem