# C++11 threading on Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, c++11

Is there anyway to use `std::thread` with C++11 standard library in windows when compiling with g++ 4.5.2 in MinGW?

I'm going assume no as I've seen many things saying you have to compile with the pthreads option but I figure I'd ask anyway.

Comment: It should work, but you'd need a newer gcc than 4.5.2 to get most of the C++0x features.  Don't know what the minimum version is for `std::thread` support under mingw.

Comment: if thread library isn't included your next best option is boost::thread

Comment: Well I was gunna use WxWidgets threading since I'm already going to be using wxWidgets for the GUI part but I wanted to check to see if I could just use the new STL in its place

Comment: @Anonymous: STL actually isn't the right term for this, STL is a very old library, whose design was mostly copied into the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: it is not C++0x anymore. It's c++11 or C++0B.

Comment: Have a look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931181/723845)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mingw-w64 threads: posix vs win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242516/mingw-w64-threads-posix-vs-win32)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is experimental support for `std::thread` in for MinGW-w64 toolchains.

Specifically, my GCC 4.6 builds provide usable `std::thread` through MinGW-w64's winpthreads library.

You can find downloads here:

- [64-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.7-experimental-stdthread/).
- [32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.7-experimental-stdthread/).

Apart from that, MSVC11 (Visual Studio 2012) has `<thread>`, `<chrono>`, and `<atomic>`. You can download the Express edition [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop).

Comment: rubenvb, is this "my GCC 4.6 builds provide usable std::thread through MinGW-w64's winpthreads .." still valid? I downloaded the i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.6.3-release-win32_rubenvb.7z and tried to use std::mutex and std:: thread but I got "thread/mutex is not member of std.

Comment: @Ragnar: You'll need the newest builds in the "experimental" subdirectory, not release. I reorganized my downloads. Let me update the links in the answer.

Comment: Scrap that: it's "old", not "experimental"

Comment: @rubenvb, I know it's much later, but is this still going on at all? I would absolutely love being able to use this without giving up the additional C++11 features and updates added in 4.7.1 and 4.7.2.

Comment: @chris see edit, and also: see my message in Lounge<C++> wrt Clang on Windows.

Comment: @rubenvb is there anyway to help get this into the stable releases and not require `-static`?

Comment: @MattClarkson as a matter of fact, the `-static` part was fixed somewhere September last year. My "experimental" is just me being careful. The only thing that happens is that code depending on the libgcc DLL will depend on the winpthreads DLL. And there might be slight performance penalties, but I have no real reports so far. Note that the Qt project uses a std::thread-enabled toolchain for their official SDK releases.

Comment: @rubenvb OK, thanks for the info.  I've only just got into using `g++` on Windows (so pretty new to all this) and have used your stable distribution, I guess I could use the experimental on from your downloads section.  Which MinGW toolchain do they use?

Answer (score 3):

There is already a lightweight native implementation of std::thread and sync primitives:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

IT is a header-only library and should work with any C++11 compliant version of MinGW. You just need to include the headers in your code.