# Code::Blocks doesn't recognize std::thread

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11 threading on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783512/c11-threading-on-windows)

The title pretty much describes it, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void task_1(){
    cout << "Thread 1" << endl;
}

int main(){
    thread task(task_1);
    task.join();
    return 1;
}
```

but it gives a compiler error

> D:\dev\cpp\trash\thread.cpp|11|error: 'thread' was not declared this scope|

I'm using Code:Blocks 10.05 with GNU GCC compiler, with option -std=c++0x

Code:Blocks was just recently downloaded so I would guess that everything should be up to date.

Comment: Umm, it should be compiler option, not linker.

Comment: Could be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414834/gcc-stdthread-not-found-in-namespace-std

Comment: `using namespace` should generally be avoided. Also `std::endl` is rarely preferable to a simple `\n`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I just set it through a checkbox, so yes, compiler option, sorry.

Comment: @AxelGneiting, Mat those threads seem to be pretty old, so I'd guess some things might just have evolved. Anyway thanks for the links, I'll check them

Comment: Try -lpthtread, that helps under Linux.

Comment: Have a look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931181/723845)

Answer (score 2):

The error you show is a compiler error, so linker options will not have any effect. You need to ensure that you're correctly configuring the compiler to support C++11 features such as `std::thread`. Using the compiler (as opposed to linker) option `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` may be all that's necessary.

Comment: I meant compiler option, sorry. There is a checkbox for it in compiler settings

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that C++11 support is still very much experimental in GCC. Support is oncoming but some regressions still exist. See http://gcc.gnu.org/