# error: 'mutex' does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

When I am try the following code in ubuntu with arm-none-eabi-g++ tool chain i was getting compilation errors:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include  <thread>    // std::thread    
#include  <mutex>    // std::mutex    
mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

commpile command :

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -Os -Wall -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -c mt.cc
```

compile error:

> mt.cc:5:1: error: 'mutex' does not name a type mutex mtx;           //
>   mutex for critical section

^

gcc version:

gcc version 4.8.4 20140725 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 213147] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ mutex in namespace std does not name a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type)

Comment: @venkat You forgot `std::`.

Comment: @Idos, no, it's not the same problem.

Comment: I did try with std:: at first here is the error I was getting "mt.cc:5:1: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section"

Answer (score 6):

You got the comment right:

```
#include  <mutex>    // std::mutex
```

But then you didn't get the code right:

```
mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section
```

That should be `std::mutex`

Comment: as I mentioned above I did try at first with std:: then I was getting this error "mt.cc:5:1: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section
 ^
"

Comment: In that case it's likely that your GCC implementation doesn't support the C++11 threading library for that ARM platform.

Comment: arm-**none**-eabi means a system with no OS, just bare metal, so you don't have most of the standard library, so no pthreads (which GCC's std::mutex is built on top of).