# error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Tags: c++, matrix, mingw, clion, armadillo

I am trying to use "**Armadillo
C++ library for linear algebra & scientific computing"** to compute the square root of a matrix. I am using JetBrains Clion ide to compute it.
I am stuck at the error:
[image]

I went through these links already:

1.) [C++ mutex in namespace std does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type)

2.) [error: 'mutex' does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083003/error-mutex-does-not-name-a-type)

3.) [C++ mutex in namespace std does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type)

I already have installed the **pthreads** package tried different flags but I am not able to resolve it. I am using MingW as :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could be a bug in armadillo. What happens if you `#include <mutex>` before `#include <armadillo>`?

Comment: Hi @TedLyngmo, I have tried adding mutex but still nothing happens.

Comment: "_nothing happens_" doesn't say much. If you add `#include <mutex>` before `#include <armadillo>` does it successfully include `mutex` or does it show an error or that line? If it successfully includes `mutex`, does it still show the same error within the armadilly code?

Comment: That particular part in armadillo seems to have moved in the newer versions. What version of armadillo are you using?

Comment: Are you sure C++11 is enabled? Adding option `-std=c++0x` to the compiler

Comment: "Nothing happens" means that I am still getting the same error even after #include<mutex> before #include "armadillo". You can see it in my first picture that I shared.

Comment: I took the latest pull from GitLab of armadillo.

Comment: @Quarra yes, I added it in CMakeLists.txt still facing the same issue.

Comment: What version of armadillo are you using? Have you tried defining `ARMA_DONT_USE_STD_MUTEX` before including `armadillo`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo please answer it so I can upvote you. Thanks.

Comment: @KhubaibAhmad Nice that it worked but I think the proper solution would be to upgrade the armadillo library. It seems like they have done a lot of changes regarding the mutexes in the 10.2.x release compared to the 9.900.x release for example. You may write an answer about the workaround to define the macro if you'd like. I just made a guess :-)