# Mutex is not a member of cv, compilation with g++ fails

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, g++, mingw

I'm trying to set up OpenCV, some basic code to just start with it and see what I can do. But every time I try to compile the app, I get errors saying 
`'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'`. Tried some of other solutions, for eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My environment is VS Code with `c_cpp_properties.json` set as this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\8.2.0\\include\\c++",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\opencv\\build\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\posix\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Tried few reinstalls of `g++` and all that `minGW` stuff, nothing works.

That's my code of `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    const string file_name = "sunflower.jpg"; 
    Mat img = imread(file_name); 
    if( !img.data ) 
    { 
        cout << "Nie odnalezionu pliku " << file_name; 
        return -1; 
    } 
    const string window_name = "OpenCV_1"; 
    namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
    imshow(window_name, img); 
    waitKey(0); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Console output

```
 Executing task: g++ -g -o bin/debug.exe src/main.cpp -IC:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include -LC:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin -llibopencv_highgui242 -llibopencv_features2d242 -llibopencv_flann242 -llibopencv_objdetect242 -llibopencv_video242 -llibopencv_calib3d242 -llibopencv_contrib242 -llibopencv_imgproc242 -llibopencv_core242 -llibopencv_ml242 -llibopencv_legacy242 -llibopencv_nonfree242 -llibopencv_photo242 -llibopencv_stitching242 -llibopencv_videostab242 <

In file included from C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core.hpp:3290,
                 from C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:48,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:697:14: error: 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:697:9: note: 'std::recursive_mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:60:1:
+#include <mutex>

C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:697:9:
 typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
         ^~~
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                             ^~~~~
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:29: note: suggested alternative: 'Matx'
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                             ^~~~~
                             Matx
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:29: note: suggested alternative: 'Matx'
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                             ^~~~~
                             Matx
C:\MinGW\lib\opencv\build\include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:698:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                                  ^
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I'm in need of a solution to configure g++ in a way to compile the application. Or do something I'm yet not aware of.

Comment: Try to add ```-std=c++11``` to ```g++``` command.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

### when you compile openCV from source on windows

see github issue [Compilation Error while running OpenCV 3.3.1 src code with MinGW and Cmake. #10272](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10272#issuecomment-357467021): **use a compiler with "posix"-configuration**. In my case `mingw-w64` did a good job.

Remember to adjust the `gcc` and `g++` paths in `cMake`, so that they do not point to some old mingw32 installation (article: [opencv+cmake+qt+win10 compile opencv library](https://www.programmersought.com/article/51784329913/))

### nasty fix for including the opencv headers

add the compiler flag `-D_M_CEE`