# Installing opencv From Command Line (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, command-line

I am trying to use opencv in a project, and am running into problems 'installing' it. I have extracted the opencv files and have created a small test program:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    cv::Mat im=cv::imread((argc==2)? argv[1]: "testing.jpg",1);
    if (im.empty()){
        std::cout << "Cannot open image." << std::endl;
    } else {
        cv::imshow("image",im);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To compile the program I have used the command below:

```
g++ -I"../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/" -L"../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib" main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -o main
```

I get the errors below:

```
In file included from ../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3293:0,
                 from ../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46,
                 from ../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:48,
                 from main.cpp:1:
../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:714:14: error: 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name
 a type
 typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:715:25: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
                         ^~
../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:715:25: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
../../PortableGit/opt/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:715:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
```

I believe that it has something to do with mingw binaries no longer being included with opencv. I am missing the `opencv/build/x86/mingw` directory.

My questions are:

- How do I 'install' opencv and use it without also installing some sort of IDE and/or CMake? (I prefer to use vim and the command line.)
- Once installed, what command do I use to compile and link a program with opencv?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**:

This appears to be a problem with GCC's implementation of [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type) on windows. Using mingw-w64 instead of mingw fixed the `std::recursive_mutex` issue, but now the linker cannot find the proper files.

```
/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_core
/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
```

Comment: It seems that OpenCV requires at least C++11. Try to compile with `-std=c++11` flag (or upgrade your compiler to at least GCC 6.1, which enables C++14 as default)

Comment: I have GCC version 6.3.0-1, and I have tried using ```-std=c++11``` but nothing changed.

Comment: That's strange, `std::recursive_mutex` was available in C++11. Adding `#include <mutex>` before OpenCV include could help (unless it's really environment problem only), but having include dependencies is far from good.

Comment: Created a small test program without opencv, and even with ```#include <mutex>```, ```std::recursive_mutex``` is not recognized.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen When you say environment problem, what things should I be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of trying things out, this is what I got to work. Oddly, following the LINUX guide to install opencv worked better than the WINDOWS guide, even though I have a windows computer.

## Guide to Installing OpenCV on Windows Without VS

*Heads-up: This is a multi-step process, 3 separate tools are required. Be prepared for this to take a while.*

#### Part 1: Get everything ready

- Download [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download).

  - On the downloads page, click on the "MinGW-w64-builds" option. Do not click on the "win-builds" option.
  - [image: MinGW-w64 builds option]
  - *The reason MinGW-w64 has to be used is because it is a newer version of the MinGW compiler suit that has been improved for windows. This means that it supports the `posix` thread system, where as the standard MinGW compiler only supports the `win32` thread system. OpenCV relies on the `posix` thread system, necessitating the MinGW-w64 compiler.*
  - Extract the MinGW-w64 zip folder to a directory. In my case its `PortableGit/opt/MinGW-w64`
  - At this point, you can add the `MingGW-w64/mingw32/bin` folder to your path. (Assuming that this won't cause any conflicts.) If you do so, you will not have to constantly specify the `g++` executable directory to run it. This is up to your discretion.
- Download an [opencv release.](https://opencv.org/releases/)

  - Do not download the package for windows, click the button that says "sources"
  - [image: Sources, not the windows package]
  - Extract the opencv sources zip folder to a directory. In my case its `PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0`
  - Also download the `opencv_contrib` source files directly from the [repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib).
  - Extract that folder and place it inside the top level opencv folder: `PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib` in my case.
- Download [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/).

  - I downloaded the zip folder, but you can download the installer if you wish.
  - Extract the CMake zip folder if you downloaded that, or run the installer. I put my CMake folder here: `PortableGit/opt/cmake-3.17.1-win32-x86`
  - At this point, you can add the `cmake-3.17.1-win32-x86/bin` folder to your path. (Assuming that this won't cause any conflicts.) If you do so, you will not have to constantly specify the `cmake` executable directory to run it. This is up to your discretion.

#### Part 2: Build OpenCV

- Navigate to the opencv directory and create a `build` folder and cd into it.

  - `mkdir build && cd build`
- Run the following export commands.

  - `export CC=/PortableGit/MinGW-w64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe`
  - `export CXX=/PortableGit/MinGW-w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe`
  - This is to make sure the next `cmake` command uses the proper compilers.
- Run the following cmake command from within that folder:
  `PortableGit/opt/cmake-3.17.1-win32-x86/cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_VS_VERSIONINFO_SKIP=1 -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="/PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules/" ..`

  - The `-G` flag specifies that we are creating build files for the MinGW compiler
  - The `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` specifies that we are building the release version of opencv and not the debug version.
  - The `DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` needs to be set to the modules folder inside the `opencv_contrib` folder. For me it was `PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/opencv_contrib/modules`
  - The `DOPENCV_VS_VERSIONINFO_SKIP` specifies to not include version info. If not set, the compiler will throw an error complaining about not having version files. (Shown below for reference.)

```
gcc: error: long: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1341:
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj] Error 1
```

- If successful, the cmake command will finish like this:

  - [image: Successfull build]
- Now run this command, again from the build folder: `/PortableGit/opt/MinGW-w64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j7`

  - `mingw32-make.exe` is the windows equivalent of the Linux `make` command.
  - The `-j7` option run the process with a maximum of 7 threads.
  - *This will take a while! It took my laptop ~20 minutes to complete*
  - If the `make` command ends in an error, make sure to reset your build directory before continuing any troubleshooting. This is done through this series of commands

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
```

#### Part 3: Using OpenCV

- To use the opencv library that you just compiled in a project of your own, compile the project with these flags from your projects main directory.
- Remember that your compiler now has to be set to the mingw-w64 compiler for opencv support.
- *I added indentation and newlines for readability, but when entering this in the terminal do not include the newlines or indents.*
- *The number at the end of the linker options may change depending on the version of opencv you downloaded. I downloaded opencv-4.3.0, making my number 430, but yours may be different.*

```
PortableGit/opt/MinGW-w64/bin/g++.exe
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/build/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/core/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/calib3d/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/dnn/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/features2d/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/flann/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/gapi/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/highgui/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/imgcodecs/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/imgproc/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/ml/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/objdetect/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/photo/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/stitching/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/ts/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/video/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/videoio/include/
    -I../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/modules/world/include/
    -L../../PortableGit/opt/opencv-4.3.0/build/lib/
    *.hpp
    *.cpp
    -lopencv_calib3d430
    -lopencv_core430
    -lopencv_dnn430
    -lopencv_features2d430
    -lopencv_flann430
    -lopencv_highgui430
    -lopencv_imgcodecs430
    -lopencv_imgproc430
    -lopencv_ml430
    -lopencv_objdetect430
    -lopencv_photo430
    -lopencv_stitching430
    -lopencv_video430
    -lopencv_videoio430
    -o
    main
```

Or you could download VS. Up to you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Correction for JackCamichael's answer
those 2 commands won't work in Windows

```
export CC=/PortableGit/MinGW-w64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
export CXX=/PortableGit/MinGW-w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
```

This should be

```
setx -m CC C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
setx -m CXX C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
```

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` is `mingw64` path on my machine