# error with <mutex> when using a library in C++, Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I am trying to use the library Armadillo in my C++ code. When I try to use it, it gives me an error: "error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"

I get the same error with the following minimalist implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mtx;
int main () {

  return 0;
}
```

I think the "mutex" library is simply not there. I am using Windows, G++ 8.1.0, MinGW-w64, and SublimeText for editing. I am adding -std=c++11 when running the file. I run the file using the following command (try_mutex.cpp is a file with the previous code):

```
g++ -std=c++11 try_mutex.cpp
```

The output is as follows:

```
try_mutex.cpp:3:6: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::mutex mtx;
      ^~~~~
try_mutex.cpp:3:1: note: 'std::mutex' is defined in header '<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
+#include <mutex>
 std::mutex mtx;
 ^~~
```

Comment: What version of GCC? Are you compiling with C++11 or greater enabled?

Comment: Besides what is already said. Are you sure that this is the only thing gcc shows as error? Because it should also show you and additional error that is something like `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.` or `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

Comment: I am using -std=c++11 when running the file from the command line. I don't get the error that you are mentioning

Comment: Please show your compiler command line and full compiler output

Comment: I added the command line and output @AlanBirtles

Comment: What is the *first* error you're getting from your compiler? Certainly this isn't the only error. You also say you're using library Armadilla, but I don't see that in your example at all? Please make sure the example you provide actually reproduces the error.

Comment: Last time I checked, there's not a GNU implementation for windows threads.  I'm not on Windows, but I have setup mingw64 to cross-compile from a linux system.

Comment: Same issue, but for an older version of mingw64 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191566/c-mutex-in-namespace-std-does-not-name-a-type