# Can I use std::thread on windows?

Tags: windows, mingw, c++11, tdm-mingw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable experimental C++0x concurrency features in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930826/how-to-enable-experimental-c0x-concurrency-features-in-mingw)

TDM-GCC complains with `error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'`

when building with `g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x`

Comment: What version..? GCC 4.4.x is supposed to support `std::thread`, so either TDM didn't get to porting it in entirety, or something's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This came from [a forum conversation](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=12701.0):

> > Question: is the level of c++0x support the same as in the linux gcc
> >     versions?
>
> Almost but not quite. Support for std::thread currently
>   relies on POSIX threads in libstdc++, which will require a
>   configuration change at least. I haven't tried it yet. Most other
>   C++0x features should work.

The closest I can get to a documented response is [the libstdc++ documentation on C++11 support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#id476343), which states that at time of writing support for class `thread` is "partial". It seems likely, if support in mainline GCC isn't done yet, that support in the TDM port is at best partial and at worst non-existent.

[This MinGW mailing list post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/33174) is somewhat more precise in its analysis of the situation as it stands now.

I'd recommend using `boost::thread` for now, for an easy switch-over in a few months' time.

Answer (score 2):

TDM GCC does not support `std::thread` out of the box at the moment. My (commercial) [Just::Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) library provides an implementation of `std::thread` for several compilers and platforms, including TDM GCC 4.5.2 on Windows.

Comment: let me know when you open source it

Comment: Ooh, that's purty... (and I'm not a zealot who will throw away anything not free)

Comment: if you need freedom use boost::thread and as a plus you won't need money either