# Is There Support for std::thread in Mingw32?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++, mingw32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable experimental C++0x concurrency features in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930826/how-to-enable-experimental-c0x-concurrency-features-in-mingw)

my version of mingw32 (gcc version is 4.5.2) does not come with the class *`std::thread`*.

Is there a version of mingw32 which supports `std::thread`?

Comment: You may be interested in: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103309/which-compilers-support-what-c11-features

Comment: And in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3414834/196561 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5930826/196561

Comment: Actually, I know that mingw32 does not support threading, I am looking for some modified version o something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that std::thread came from boost, so you can always use boost for that, plus it comes with lots of useable bits

Answer (score 1):

Mingw32 is on the overly conservative side, for updated compiler technology follow MinGW-w64 which targets both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

It limits you to Cygwin or Linux et al. cross compiles, there isn't a choice available for MSYS.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful. But mingw-w64 (seems to) also doesn't support threading yet.

Comment: I recall there were "posix" and "winapi" threading schemes mentioned when I was downloading recent mingw-w64 versions. are you sure?

Comment: oops, i did not realize i'm 5 years late...