# C++0x random_device with 'std::runtime_error'

Tags: c++, qt, random, c++11

I am a C++ beginner and I have a problem with C++0x random number generator. I wanted to use Mersenne twister engine for generating random int64_t numbers, and I wrote a function using some information I've found earlier:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>

int64_t MyRandomClass::generateInt64_t(int64_t minValue, int64_t maxValue)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e( rd() );
    unsigned char arr[8];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (unsigned char)e();
    }
    int64_t number = static_cast<int64_t>(arr[0]) | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[1]) << 8 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[2]) << 16 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[3]) << 24 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[4]) << 32 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[5]) << 40 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[6]) << 48 | static_cast<int64_t>(arr[7]) << 56;
    return (std::abs(number % (maxValue - minValue)) + minValue);
}
```

When I'm trying to use this code in Qt application, I'm getting this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  random_device::random_device(const std::string&)
```

As I said before, I'm not very familiar with C++, but it looked like I had to specify a `const std::string` value. I tried this:

```
const std::string s = "s";
std::random_device rd(s);
```

But it leads to the same error. How can I avoid it?

I use MinGW 4.7 32bit compiler and Desktop Qt 5.0.1 on Windows platform. I also wrote `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` in .pro file.

Comment: Please stop creating random engines every time you ask for a random number. Create one as a member of an object and ask it for a new random number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in MinGW (also detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12351142/1204143)). Basically, MinGW does not have a Windows-specific implementation of `random_device`, so it just tries to open `/dev/urandom`, fails, and throws `std::runtime_error`.

VS2012's `std::random_device` works, as does simply using `mt19937` or another generator directly.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I will try to not use std::random_device.

Comment: Seems like now it compiles but allays returns the same numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-same-sequence-for-everyrun-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw-gcc4

Comment: What is VS2012? **EDIT:** Visual Studio 2012, oh ok. Well, I'm using Code::block, damn…