# problems in seeding random number in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I used the following code (copied somewhere from the web) and managed to generate some an array of random numbers.

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0,1);

int N;
std::cout<< "Please enter the number of disks to be generated: ";
std::cin>> N;

// generates N pairs of coordinates
double** R;
R = new double* [N];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    R[i] = new double [3];
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        R[i][j] = distribution(generator);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the output is always the same, so I think it is not seeded properly. Then I found the following code from the web, but it didn't work on my computer (I always get runtime error)

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1, 2);
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

What's wrong with the above code? How to seed my code so I can get different outputs everytime? Besides, for the first code, is the linear congruential algorithm being used? How to use 'better' algorithm like the Mersenne Twister (mt19937) ?

thanks

Comment: 2ns snippet [works for me](https://ideone.com/UYormG). Error is somewhere else

Comment: On the C++ side, you can use a `std::vector<double> R(N*3);` to store all those doubles, instead of horribly nested `new[]`.

Comment: @Drop it works on gcc, but it can not works on another platforms/compilers.

Comment: @Tino Didriksen if I use vector isn't it one-dimensional? I just want to make it two-dimensional so that it 'looks' better to me.

Comment: @Physicist `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` is two-dimensional vector.

Comment: 2D vector is kind of an abomination when you can use 1D and some simple math, but it's still better than nested new[]. Alternatively, use Boost.Multi_array.

Comment: @ForEveR Why wouldn't it work on another platform?

Comment: @Drop for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725677/c0x-random-device-with-stdruntime-error

Comment: @ForEveR an isolated ancient compiler/standard library (port) bug doesn't mean the code is incorrect. I mean the answer to a question `"What's wrong with the above code? "` is: "Nothing, it's correct".

Comment: @Drop in this case you are right, but `Error is somewhere else` is wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[default_random_engine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is implementation-defined. It's not specified which algo it will use.

Which `runtime_error` you get? It should work correct, but as workaround, you can seed `mt19937` with current time as with `srand`.

```
std::mt19937 gen(static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::time(nullptr)));
```

Comment: thanks, now it works, but do you mind explaining 'static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>' in more details please?

Comment: @Physicist `mt19937` ctor receives arg of type `result_type`. `time` will returns `time_t`. So, just cast to `result_type`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly seed the random number generator in the constructor with something like this (this example uses the system clock to uniquely seed the generator):

```
  // obtain a seed from the timer
  unsigned seed = myclock::now().count();
  //construct the generator
  std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a random seed for the random number generators.  (BTW, the library default of producing the same numbers in the generators is so test results can be predictable).  I use the system time as others have shown.

One way I haven't seen mentioned is std::seed_seq which addresses this very issue.  Feed is a few integers and it produces a nice sequence of seeds:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

unsigned long
system_now()
{
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now{std::chrono::system_clock::now()};
  std::chrono::system_clock::duration epoch{now.time_since_epoch()};
  return static_cast<unsigned long>(now.time_since_epoch().count());
}

int
main()
{
    // ...
    auto N = 500;

    std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> R(N);

    std::seed_seq seq{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> seeds(1000);
    seq.generate(seeds.begin(), seeds.end());

    std::mt19937 generator(seeds[system_now() % seeds.size()]);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution{0.0, 1.0};

    for (auto & V : R)
        for (auto & C : V)
            C = distribution(generator);

    for (const auto & V : R)
    {
        std::cout << '(';
        for (const auto & C : V)
            std::cout << ' ' << std::setw(10) << C;
        std::cout << " )\n";
    }
}
```

Warning! The seed sequence is also repeatable - with the same input it returns the same output!  Also, with 1000 seeds you'll eventually set the same numbers again.  Same seed, same generated numbers.