# How do i generete events with multithread and how do i synchronize them in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, event-handling, synchronization

I have a project that needs multiple thread and event generation in c++. I have 4 different sensors send data and a user interface that use TCP. They must run at the same time.
I have a TCP class that has functions to check connection, send messages and get messages. Each these of function need to generate event(for example in checkConnection() function generate an event when connection fail or ok, in getMessages() function generate an event when message received etc.). I have 5 threads, 4 of them for sensor data and 1 of them for user interface. But i couldn't generate events in c++. How do i generate events and how do i use them with threads? Do you have any example about this?

Comment: What kind of events? Windows events? Qt events? Do you want to setup an own event system?

Comment: I am using windows OS but i want to design platform-independent events. @Scheff

Comment: OK. So, you want to design your own event system. This is something worth to be [edit]ed in, isn't it?

Comment: This is what I found with [google "c++ event system tutorial"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+event+system+tutorial): [**CppEvent - How to Implement Events using Standard C++**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1256352/CppEvent-How-to-Implement-Events-using-Standard-Cp)

Comment: Your central facility has to be an event queue. (`std::deque` could be appropriate or `std::queue`.) To generate events, add entries to the end of queue. To process events, take them from front of queue (if queue is not empty). Processing of events could be done in a loop by registered function handlers or (even simpler) in a `switch`. Of course, with multi-threading, you have to add thread sync. So, your event queue should use e.g. a `std::mutex` to make concurrent accesses for sending and processing of events mutual exclusive.

Comment: To prevent unecessary looping while waiting on an event in your main thread, a `std::condition_variable` could be used to make the event process function blocking (until an event is arrived). Example in my answer to [SO: C/C++: How to exit sleep() when an interrupt arrives?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61496169/7478597)

Comment: You probably should think twice before you go multithreaded. Maybe single threaded works, too. And it is much easier.

Comment: Thank you @Scheff. These are very useful for me.