MPI 100% CPU usage while waiting
I have a Fortran program that uses the MPICH library. At some point, the program rank 0 calls an external program, which itself uses OPENMP while other ranks wait in an MPI_BARRIER. My issue is that waiting processes stay at 100% CPU usage. I want to be able to use resources from waiting processes to speed up my OpenMP program running on rank 0.
Is there a way to control the busy mode of MPICH? I've seen threads but they mainly concern OpenMPI and not MPICH (e.g. --mca mpi_yield_when_idle 1). I believe I would need the MPICH equivalent of --mca mpi_yield_when_idle 1 but I can't find it.
Thank you for your help and comments

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33892/cpu-usage-when-a-mpi-rank-waits-during-a-blocking-communication may be of interest

You're trying to second guess the implementation which is rarely a good thing to do, and limits you that implementation - and by Murphy's law the implementation will change the moment you have it working. If you are on a POSIX system I would look into using sleep() on the processes you want to sleep, and waking them with a user defined signal from the root process once it has done what it wants to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568033/wake-up-a-process-from-sleep-with-a-signal might be of use.

Thanks for pointing me to this link, i'll have a look and let you know

There are so many things that can go wrong in the scenario you're describing that I'm not sure you've got the right approach. However, you still might want to explore the MPICH_POLLS_BEFORE_YIELD environment variable.

Thank you for your comment. Trust me I don't like this approach, but I cannot think of an other way for now. I have a main program using domain decomposition MPI. This program has to call periodically an other algorithm acting on the whole domain which is close to impossible to write using the same domain decomposition paradigm. Most I can do to speed up this algo is paralellizing some parts with OPENMP. I could not go back to this issue yet, I hope I will soon and let you know.

@Gilles I tried to play with the mentionned env variable by setting in the terminal export MPICH_POLLS_BEFORE_YIELD=X, X=different values 0,1 and much higher values than default one which is 1000. It does not have a clear impact, waiting CPUs are still running 100%. Am I doing something wrong ? Unfortunately I do not find much ressources online about these env vars.

In the end I used a trick as suggested by @Ian Bush . I set all but rank 0 processes in sleep mode and wake them up once rank 0 has finished. To do that rank 0 writes an external empty file once its job is finished and other processes wake up when this file is available. I know this is not very elegant and the approach is questionnable but it does the job done for now. Many thanks for your help.

You should be able to do it without an external file by some probe for a message.
